# 16.04 AMD Graphics card not used properly

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I just updated to 16.04. My system has AMD Radeon HD 5450 graphics card which I use with two 16:9 monitors.

After update, i.e., after removing fglrx, the displays are mirrored and have 4:3 aspect ratio and low resolution. I suspect this has something to do with the driver in use, but I'm unable to change it.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

```
$ sudo lspci -v
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at fbe20000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at fbe00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
Kernel modules: radeon
```

Some other possibly useful information:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fbe20000-fbe3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fbe00000-fbe1ffff
```

Comment: I fixed a similar issue using xrandr. Execute `xrandr` to get output infos, max resolution, etc. Then do `xrandr --output OUTPUT --mode MAXRES`, replacing OUTPUT with the output name of your monitor (cf. the output of `xrandr`, probably VGA-1 in your case), and MAXRES with the maximum resolution of your screen, as shown using the `xrandr` command. This should look something like `xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to remove `nomodeset` from kernel parameters in grub. This enabled `radeon` driver and dual monitor setup with correct resolutions was immediately correct after startup.

Unfortunately the `radeon` driver (and/or perhaps the GPU itself) seems to be little on the slow side with current desktop environments using dual monitor with multiple windows open etc.

Comment: This worked for me with amdgpu-pro